# Flex Timer issue

Tags: flash, flex4, timer, air

The Timer in my class does not seem to fire any TIMER events at all when the interval is more than 5 seconds or after it has measured 5 seconds. I need to measure 30 seconds.

Here's my code

```
//class ctor
public function myClass() {
    tmr=new Timer(5000, 6);
    tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);
    tmr.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTrace);
}
private function timerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("complete");
}
private function timerTrace(e:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("tick|" + tmr.currentCount);
}
```

The output I get is

```
tick|1
```

When I change the interval to 1000ms and the repeatCount to 30, I get

```
tick|1
tick|2
tick|3
tick|4
```

When interval is 30000 and repeatCount is 1, I get no output

The timer never completes.

I tried using setTimeout, but the timeout of 30 seconds doesn't work there either.

How can I add a timeout of 30 seconds?

**EDIT**

```
//declare timer
public var tmr as Timer;

//external class
nyClassInstance.tmr.start();
```

Comment: I assume you are saving your tmr variable somewhere outside of scope?  Sounds like your timer could be getting garbage collected?

Comment: Are you starting your timer somewhere else in the code? ".start();"

Comment: It shouldn't be garbage collected if there are still references to it through the listeners

Comment: The timer is stored as a public var and it is started externally

Comment: The weird thing is that it stops responding after 5 seconds

Comment: um where is tmr.start()?

Comment: @Exort, the `Timer` could still be collected, even with listeners, all `EventDispatcher` objects maintain the list of handler callbacks themselves.

Comment: @The_asMan, tmr.start() is in another class which instantiates an object of myClass

Comment: @Peter there is a strong reference to the timer in the public variable of the class, not just a weak reference which can be garbage-collected randomly

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks, I understand that, I was responding to Exort's comment. Adding event handler's alone (strong or weak) is not sufficient to prevent garbage collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to set the delay to 30 seconds you should do it like this:

```
_timer = new Timer(30 * 1000, 1);
_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
_timer.start();
```

Example: http://wonderfl.net/c/4duo/

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class FlashTest extends Sprite
    {
        private var _timer : Timer;
        private var _lastUpdate : int;
        private var _debugText : TextField;

        public function FlashTest()
        {
            _debugText = new TextField();
            addChild(_debugText);

            _lastUpdate = getTimer();

            _timer = new Timer(6 * 1000, 6);
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimerUpdate);
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
            _timer.start();

            _debugText.appendText("STARTED");
        }

        private function onTimerUpdate(event : TimerEvent) : void
        {
            _debugText.appendText("\n" + (getTimer() - _lastUpdate) + " - UPDATE " + _timer.currentCount);

            _lastUpdate = getTimer();
        }

        private function onTimerComplete(event : TimerEvent) : void
        {
            _debugText.appendText("\nCOMPLETE");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think something in your code stops the Timer from completing. The timer is not the issue here.

Comment: I wrote the test `myClass` to confirm this, and it still happens. There is absolutely nothing stopping the timer.

Comment: If that is a testclass, why not start the timer inside the class also? Skip everything that does not have to do with the test class for a moment.

Comment: because in my real class, I am starting the timer externally

Comment: I am just saying ... If you get your test class functionality to work first, then you know it works and  can backtrace the problem.

Comment: As it turns out, the external class was calling `timer.reset()`
I asked the developer to remove those lines and it works. by the way, there is no need to instantiate as `new Timer(30 * 1000, 1);`. `new Timer(30000, 1);` works just as well.